# How can I use New-EC2Tag correct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, powershell-3.0, aws-powershell

I use powershell script to change Name tag as below :

```
New-EC2Tag -Resource $aws_instance_id -Tag @{Key="Name"; Value="WINTEST"}
```

but  I always receive output message like this :

```
New-EC2Tag : No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.
```

and the script not work. Something wrong with the command ? Please help me, I search it but i can't find correct answer for my problem.

Comment: You need to specify your AWS account credentials, `New-EC2Tag` is failing because they haven't been specified.  Read here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html and please edit your question with more details if it is still failing after you've correctly passed your credentials.

Comment: ok, it worked thank you!

Answer (score 1):

AWS credentials need to be provided unless the machine from which command is run have an instance profile with AWS and with required permissions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/